# $ps -ax shows long-running "windows server"

Tags: macos, windows-server, pid, macos-monterey

When executing the `ps -ax` command, I see the following:

```
  158 ??       294:09.79 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Resources/WindowServer -daemon
```

It is far and away the longest running program that shows up, and it seems suspicious to me. I have never run any virtual windows machine on my computer (I have used docker, as well as logged into remote desktops, but never any virtual machines).

When I try to `sudo kill 158` nothing happens, just keeps running.

I am tempted to just `rm -r` everything in the `SkyLight.framework` directory, but I thought I'd ask first.

Thank you to anyone who can shed light on what this is.

Comment: Fortunately, it wouldn't have let you delete it, just like it won't let you quit it… otherwise you'd need to reinstall the OS to be able to see the screen again ;) [The answers below have fuller explanations as to why you don't want to do that.]

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't say "Windows Server" – it says "**Window** Server".

A window server is the OS component which handles the display of application windows on your screen – such as their stacking order, positioning, focus (i.e. delivering input to the right window), and composing individual windows into the single final image.

Here's a longer explanation of the macOS 'WindowServer' specifically:

- https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/08/windowserver-display-compositor-and-input-event-router/

It is also known as "Quartz Compositor" (Quartz being the entire macOS GUI environment):

- https://web.archive.org/web/20040925095929/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/COnceptual/SystemOverview/SystemArchitecture/chapter_3_section_4.html

Similarly, `Xorg` on Linux would be "window server" for the X Window System aka X11 (though it does leave quite a few tasks to a separate window manager program), and `dwm.exe` may be the closest equivalent in Windows.

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly now hahah

Answer (score 1):

#### I am tempted to just `rm -r` everything in the `SkyLight.framework` directory

I don't think you want to do that.

> WindowServer is a core part of macOS, and a liaison of sorts between
> your applications and your display. If you see something on your Mac’s
> display, WindowServer put it there. Every window you open, every
> website you browse, every game you play—WindowServer “draws” it all on
> your screen. You can [read more at Apple’s developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION14) if
> you’re technically inclined, but it’s not exactly light reading.
>
> For the most part, just know that WindowServer is what macOS, and
> every application you run on it, uses in order to display things on
> your screen. **It is completely safe**.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [What Is the Process WindowServer, and Why Is It Running on My Mac?](https://www.howtogeek.com/312755/what-is-the-process-windowserver-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-mac/)

Comment: Also Skylight is the new name for the CoreGraphicsServices framework, another critical component.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!